# Learning C++, I can't read the code on nano from terminal

Tags: 16.04, c++

I write a C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string password;
    cout << "Ingrese su password: " << "\n";
    getline( cin, password, '\n' );

    if ( password == "xyz123" )
        {
            cout << "Access Permitido" << "\n";
        }
    else
        {
            cout << "XD!, Acceso Denegado" << "\n";
            // returning is a convenient way to stop the program
            return 0;
        }
    // continue onward!
}
```

It run on Windows! I write `nano password.cpp` and then the following error appears:

```
Error opening file locking "./. password.cpp.swp":...
```

[image: error opening file locking "./. password.cpp.swp":...]

Comment: So... the file is *located* on a Windows partition, and you are trying to edit it from Ubuntu using `nano`?

Answer (score 2):

Use the command

```
rm .password.cpp.swp
```

This should remove the temporary file generated by nano. After that, you can try opening it again with nano.

Comment: you can not erase password.cpp.swp, the file does not exist

Comment: with the starting point:you can not erase .password.cpp.swp, the file does not exist

Comment: Can you try copying the file to ~/Documents or something and try opening it from there?

Comment: The file isn't in Güin2, so a erase it, and write all again in a new fle, and it works, thanks for all anyway, XD..